# Errors when running jest on typescript using Type Guards

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have this type:

```
export type NameValidationResult =
    | {
          success: true;
      }
    | {
          success: false;
          errorMessage: string;
      };
```

and I am using this type in this part of the code:

```
   let nameValidationResult: NameValidationResult = this.getNameValidation();

    if (nameValidationResult.success) {
        return "this is success";
    }

     return nameValidationResult.errorMessage;
}
```

When I compile, there are no errors (also no runtime errors)

I have this test:

```
describe("name validator tests", () => {
    test("test name validator success", async () => {
        const result: string = await NameValidator.validateName("testname");

        if (result != "this is success") {
            fail("fail test");
        }
    });
});
```

When I run Jest, I am getting this error:

```
Property 'errorMessage' does not exist on type '{ success: true; }

     return nameValidationResult.errorMessage;
```

When I run this code:

how can I fix this?

The problem is the test doesn't run, I put a break point and I don't reach it.
If I remove the line:

```
return nameValidationResult.errorMessage;
```

with the line

```
return "Error message"
```

Then the test run and pass (also stop on breakpoint)

Comment: Works for me: https://tsplay.dev/GNlalm Could you paste full test?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I added the test in the main post

Comment: code looks correct. the problem is somewhere outside